# Feminine version of colloquial use 'hi man'

Tags: expressions, colloquialisms, greetings

When a man greets another man, he often says 'hi man', 'thanks man', etc. I am wondering whether these expressions have feminine use. I never heard a woman greeting another woman with 'hi woman'. Any thoughts?

Comment: to be clear you mean how A FEMALE would speak addressing another female.

Comment: Yes I mean that.

Comment: I am a woman and I regularly say things like "Hey, man, I don't think you should do that" (to non-forcefully introduce correction in a classroom) and say things like "Thanks, man", "You're the best, man", etc. I actually picked it up from a female friend of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, while a man may say, "Hi/Hey Man," or "Thanks, Man," to another - regardless of whether he knows him or not - women generally do not use the same familiarity.

In a very informal situation - say, a party or, the ladies' room in a bar - a woman may greet another she does not know with "Hey Girl," but only if the woman is apparently a contemporary, or younger.

Women who are acquainted may say, "Hi/Hey Lady/Girl/Woman," to greet each other, and the same with "Thanks".

Comment: Indeed.  it's a great question and kind of has no answer! As far as I know females just say "hi" or "excuse me" without a naming word.  Men as pointed out can say "hey man" or even "say, buddy" etc...

Comment: From your answer, it is interesting to note that men shows familiarity by saying 'hi/hey man' but women generally do not. In fact, I never heard two acquainted women greeting each other by 'hi lady/girl/woman.'

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to for people to use the word *lady* or *girl* in place of *man*. As applied to your examples, "hey lady" or "thanks, girl/gurl" sound natural to me. Most definitely, "woman" is not used in such phrases, however.

Comment: After asking about 100 women in my circle of conversation about this, we have hovered closer to *girl* with variations of *hi*, *hey* and *thanks*.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States one might say *[mam](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mam)*:

> 2 A term of respectful or polite address used for any woman:

<sub>ODO</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I say hey woman, I'm a girl. To my girl friends I would say "hey my woman" I would even say when I'm calling out to someone "woman" I guess maybe it's just slang from where I live in australia.